# REST API Url for multiple actors performing same actions

Tags: rest, api, api-design

Consider a resource on which multiple actors can perform same action. An example can be mortgage loan, for which both bank and rating agency can approve or decline the mortgage loan request.
Here are some options on how the API can be structured:

a) Actor is part of url
/loan/{id}/bank/approve
/loan/{id}/ratingagency/approve

b) Actor is part of header
/loan/{id}/approve
x-actor: bank | ratingagency

Advantages of a)
1. From  access logs, it will be easier to identify actor and action
2. From microservices architecture perspective, the deployment and scaling of the APIs may be easier if the scaling requirements of bank approval is different from rating agency approval. Not sure if this is possible with headers as well(?)

Advantages of b)
1. More in line with REST principals (?)
Any others?

For a), it can be argued that APIs with sub-resources are structured like this. By extension, same can be applied to different actors with same action.

Looking for suggestion/opinions on above two approaches.

Comment: In a REST architecture the spelling of the URI does not matter as clients will determine whether to invoke the URI based on an accompanying URI anyways. There is this myth, @Evert talks about, that verbs in URIs are a bad smell, but as said, a computer will not care whether the URI contains a verb or a noun. Next, you can probably deduce the bank from the authenticated user and return information specific to his or her employee

Comment: Agree that it can be deduced from authenticated user. However, in some cases (not in the example above) - authenticated user may be in multiple roles. The 2 advantages listed for Option 1 - a), will not be there if API is designed int this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Action urls aren't really RESTful to begin with. Regardless, it's perfectly ok for exposing ceratain things on multiple uris. Sounds like this might be a good design decisions. A good REST client and server model doesn't care about the structure of your uri's though, it should discover them.

Comment: Thanks Evert. In addition to the 2 reasons for for exposing on multiple uris, can you suggest of any other reason for this? Also, if you had to develop this, would you pick approach a0 or b) or anything else? The reason I am asking is because of your deep experience in developing REST APIs.

Comment: "A REST API should spend almost all of its descriptive effort in defining the media type(s) used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and/or hypertext-enabled mark-up for existing standard media types. Any effort spent describing what methods to use on what URIs of interest should be entirely defined within the scope of the processing rules for a media type (and, in most cases, already defined by existing media types). [Failure here implies that out-of-band information is driving interaction instead of hypertext.]"

Comment: That quote is from the person who came up with REST. I don't think url design is very important here. I would however not have an action-style url, but instead I would try to define a resource which (maybe in your case) is a loan application(?) with a property `approved` which gets set to true.

Comment: I tend to not duplicate resources multiple times, but that's because my resource for your example might look like `/loan-application/1234`. If that resource exists in multiple spots on the tree, it might cause a developer to think that they are not the same thing.

Comment: I'm not too worried about access logs, because I have a good logging infrastructure where I can send custom messages.